# changing a name of a ` character vector` within a loop in r

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, assign, backticks

I am working in R  and I have  a few lists named `` `sample 1` ``, `` `sample 2` `` (within backtick quotes) and I want to assign  each of them to a variable  with the corresponding sample number with a loop. Problem is that I can not assign the i inside the backticks. Does anyone knows how to modify a loop inside a backtick-quoted name?

```
>#example of one of the lists

> print(`sample 1`)

[1] "New AS Plate 21_AS Plate_Sample 1_100.fcs" "New AS Plate 21_AS Plate_Sample 1_25.fcs" 
[3] "New AS Plate 21_AS Plate_Sample 1_250.fcs" "New AS Plate 21_AS Plate_Sample 1_50.fcs" 
[5] "New AS Plate 21_AS Plate_Sample 1_500.fcs"

>#function i would like to loop

> flowdata1= print(`sample 1`)

> flowdata1

[1] "New AS Plate 21_AS Plate_Sample 1_100.fcs" "New AS Plate 21_AS Plate_Sample 1_25.fcs" 
[3] "New AS Plate 21_AS Plate_Sample 1_250.fcs" "New AS Plate 21_AS Plate_Sample 1_50.fcs" 
[5] "New AS Plate 21_AS Plate_Sample 1_500.fcs"

>#loop that doesn´work

> for(i in 1:18) {
+   assign(paste0("flowdata", i), print(`sample i`))}
```

> Error in print(`sample i`) : object 'sample i' not found

I am not sure if there is an alternative way to create these lists `sample x` so that they are named sample x. I created them with a loop that divided a list of 18 sublist and assigned the samples names from a sublist. Please note that i don´t want to assign a name of these new lists with the iteration number (i) as they are in a non consecutive order...

```
> for(i in 1:length(split.names)) {                   
  assign(names(split.names[i]), split.names[[i]])}

> print(sample 1)
```

> Error: unexpected numeric constant in "print(sample 1"

```
> print(`sample 1`)

[1] "New AS Plate 21_AS Plate_Sample 1_100.fcs" "New AS Plate 21_AS Plate_Sample 1_25.fcs" 
[3] "New AS Plate 21_AS Plate_Sample 1_250.fcs" "New AS Plate 21_AS Plate_Sample 1_50.fcs" 
[5] "New AS Plate 21_AS Plate_Sample 1_500.fcs"
```

So the way i ended up with this variable names was:

```
#list with 90 names

> length(sample.names.dilutions)

[1] 90

#example of names in list

> head(sample.names.dilutions)

[1] "New AS Plate 21_AS Plate_Sample 1_100.fcs"  "New AS Plate 21_AS Plate_Sample 1_25.fcs"  
[3] "New AS Plate 21_AS Plate_Sample 1_250.fcs"  "New AS Plate 21_AS Plate_Sample 1_50.fcs"  
[5] "New AS Plate 21_AS Plate_Sample 1_500.fcs"  "New AS Plate 21_AS Plate_Sample 10_100.fcs"

> #divide  list in 18 sublists applying split() function

> num.samples<- 18
> split.names <- split(sample.names.dilutions, cut(seq_along(sample.names.dilutions), num.samples, labels = FALSE))


> #create list of sample names with non consecutive numbers
> prefix <- "sample"
> suffix <- c(1,10:18,2:9)
> sample.names <- paste(prefix,suffix)

> # assign names to sublist
> names(split.names) <- sample.names

> # assign function within loop to create sample names with  specific sublist names
> for(i in 1:length(split.names)) {                   
+   assign(names(split.names[i]), split.names[[i]])}
```

Comment: Backtick quotes ≠ single quotes!

Comment: The obvious question here would be: **why** do you have such variable names, where are they coming from? They shouldn’t exist, instead they should be vectors or lists. Having consecutive numbers in variable names is essentially never appropriate! You should solve that fundamental issue rather than attempting to work around it.

Comment: One more issue: assigning the result of `print` is decidedly odd. Instead of `x = print(y)` you can just use `x = y`. If you also want to print the value, *do it in a separate statement*. The current code is confusing and likely unintentional.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @KonradRudolph, I am very new to R and I have created those variable in an attempt to divide a list of 90 names by order into chunks of 5. So creating a list with 18 sub lists  then assigning  specific names to the sublists and finally creating 18 list with a loop as shown above.  I am not sure if there is a different way to create variables from a long list and assigning specific names.. I am open to suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm and how did you divide the list? I’m assuming you did so manually? Because no function in R would create separate variables. What you want instead is a single list of vectors. You can automatically create such a list from an input vector with the functions [`cut`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cut.html) and [`split`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/split.html); for instance: `samples = split(your_filename_vector, cut(seq_along(your_filename_vector), 10L))` would separate a vector of file names into 10 vectors, all stored in `samples`.

Comment: Thanks @KonradRudolph , yeah so I have added the code used to split the list and assign specific names. I did use the cut() and split() function...

Comment: Hi carolina, your data seems to be neatly stored in a list (`split.names`), there's no need to assign variables: just use the list directly :)

Comment: You can access your sample data via `split.names[["sample 1"]]` -- I'd suggest renaming the list to something more explicit, maybe `sample_list`. Also, if you create your labels using `paste0` rather than `paste`, you'll get rid of the space which will allow you to access your elements without quotes or backticks, using e.g. `sample_list$sample2`. In fact, your labels may not be useful at all as you could simply do `sample_list[2]` to access the second set of samples.

Comment: Thank you @asachet that sounds like a good idea I had not thought about. Will give it a go.

Comment: @asachet  what if I would l like to assign a name to each of those subset something sample.2 = sample_list$sample2  but with a loop as I have many samples and they are not necessarily in a consecutive order.  something like  for(i in 1:18) {sample.i  = sample_list$samplei}

Comment: @carolina671 but why assign them in the first place? What do you achieve by storing `sample_list[[2]]` in a variable `sample.2`... Beyond making life much harder for you as you won't be able to easily perform operation on all them?

Comment: What you describe when you write `for(i in 1:18){sample.i = sample_list$samplei} is precisely the use case for lists, you need to understand that. If you call your `split.names` simply `sample`, then sample[[2]] is your second sample. That's it. You gain nothing by destroying the list and storing its elements in many separate variables.

Comment: Thank you @asachet, you have made a good point!